# How to read _popen directly without piping it to file?

Tags: visual-c++

How can I write the output of this line of code to a float variable instead of piping it to a file? The output of this line is a floating number.

```
FILE  *child = _popen("java -jar c:\\simmetrics.jar c:\\chtml.txt c:\\thtml.txt", "r");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to read from your file descriptor:

```
float value;
fscanf(child, "%f", &value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d;
fscanf(child, "%lf", &d);
```